# Implementing method error message

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm working on a web service to send an email. When i run my application I get the following error:

`The method or operation is not implemented.`

My Code in my website looks like:

```
WebTestServiceApp.localhost.Service1 Send = new WebTestServiceApp.localhost.Service1();
        Send.Sendemail(txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtbody.Text);
```

My code in my webService looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Sendemail( String inValueTo, String inValueSub, String inValueBody) 
    {try
        {
            String valueTo = inValueTo;
            String valueSub = inValueSub;
            String valueBody = inValueBody;
           // String valueAttachmentPostedfile = inValueAttachmentPostedfile; //FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
          //  String valueAttachmentFileContent = inValueAttachemtnFileContent;  //FileUpload1.FileContent.fileName

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(); // Creating new message.

            message.To.Add(valueTo);
            message.Subject = valueSub;
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("shaunmossop@mweb.co.za");
            message.Body = valueBody;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(valueAttachmentPostedfile); // Get attachment file
           //  Attachment myAttachment =
           //                  new Attachment(valueAttachmentFileContent, fileName);
           //   if (fileName != "")
           //   {
           //       message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment); // Send attachment
           //   }

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"); //Properties.Settings.Default.MailSMTPServer

            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            NetworkCredential netC = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.username, Properties.Settings.Default.password); // Useing Projects defult settings.
            smtp.Credentials = netC;
            smtp.Send(message);

            return "Message has been sent";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Message faild to send" ;

        }}
```

The rest of the code in the webService works, i know this because i used it in a working website, my problem is just passing the values though or a step i'm missing in the webService.

Can anyone see a obvious problem and what am i doing wrong, iv used webservices in VB but not C# so is there a difference?

Comment: What exactly is the `......` in the `Sendemail` method? Just a `throw new NotImplementedException()`?.

Comment: There i replaced the ....., What do u mean by throw new NotImplementedException()

Comment: Maybe the **Web Reference** has not been updated, did you try updating the same ?

Comment: Ah i hate web, always have to update! but ja it worked, thanks a million man, saved my life :) should of put it in a answer so i can mark u as correct :D Thanks Thanks Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the Web Reference has not been updated for your current application and hence it might be linking to the case wherein the method was not implemented.

So the only way to get it checked and working would be to Try update the Web Reference.